# How to install mcrypt on Docker

Tags: docker, mcrypt, php-extension

I have a Docker Container with Phalcon3 and php 7. I am trying to install the php extension Mcrypt without luck.

If I do ssh to the container, and execute:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt
```

I get the following:

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-mcrypt
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-mcrypt'
```

Is there a way to get it installed?

Comment: you should always begin with a `apt-get update` so try something along the lines of `apt-get update && apt-get install -y php7.0-mcrypt` the update first is necessary because you may use an OS (ubuntu, Debian or such) that has had many updates since its arrival. By the way, `sudo` is not necessary, you are root unless you do `USER myuser`

Comment: have a look at https://hub.docker.com/r/phpdocker/phpdocker/~/dockerfile/ (and the line `FROM php:7.1-fpm` is built on Debian)

Comment: @user2915097 Sorry, yes I do apt-get update, and you are right sudo is not necesary in fact it complains about it. I updated the commands.
Also Im traying to modify an existing container, not creating a new one, as you recommend on your second comment.

Comment: Post the Dockerfile, it will be simpler

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lets look at official manual for  [php docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) **Section PHP Core Extensions**

> For example, if you want to have a PHP-FPM image with iconv, mcrypt
>   and gd extensions, you can inherit the base image that you like, and
>   write your own Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

> Rember, you must install dependencies for your extensions manually. If
>   an extension needs custom configure arguments, you can use the
>   docker-php-ext-configure script like this example. There is no need to
>   run docker-php-source manually in this case, since that is handled by
>   the configure and install scripts.

Comment: Thank you that was great help.
You can also ssh on the container and execute that same command:
apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

Answer (score 30):

From PHP manual:

This extension has been moved to the » PECL repository and is no longer bundled with PHP as of PHP 7.4.0.

So in your Dockerfile you have to:

```
RUN apt-get install libmcrypt-dev
RUN pecl install mcrypt-1.0.4 && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt
```

Comment: Seems to work, but under Lando not completely. Or do I need add something there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752814/how-to-install-php-mcrypt-in-lando-with-php-7-2