# Docker-php-ext-install mcrypt missing folder

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, mcrypt, php-7.2

I try to install mcrypt in my docker image based on `php:7.2-apache`. Therefore I use the RUN-Command from the documentation and also answerd [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181369/how-to-install-mcrypt-on-docker) but I receive this error:

```
error: /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt does not exist


usage: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install [-jN] ext-name [ext-name ...]

   ie: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install gd mysqli
   /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
   /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install -j5 gd mbstring mysqli pdo pdo_mysql shmop

if custom ./configure arguments are necessary, see docker-php-ext-configure

Possible values for ext-name:
bcmath bz2 calendar ctype curl dba dom enchant exif fileinfo filter ftp  gd gettext gmp hash iconv imap interbase intl json ldap mbstring mysqli oci8  odbc opcache pcntl pdo pdo_dblib pdo_firebird pdo_mysql pdo_oci pdo_odbc pdo_pgsql pdo_sqlite pgsql phar posix pspell readline recode reflection session shmop simplexml snmp soap sockets sodium spl standard sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm tidy tokenizer wddx xml xmlreader xmlrpc xmlwriter xsl zend_test zip

Some of the above modules are already compiled into PHP; please check
the output of "php -i" to see which modules are already loaded.
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y          libfreetype6-dev          libjpeg62-turbo-dev          libmcrypt-dev          libpng-dev     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt gd mbstring zip' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
     libfreetype6-dev \
     libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
     libmcrypt-dev \
     libpng-dev \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt gd mbstring zip
#    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
#    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd


COPY ./etc/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/

EXPOSE 80
```

Has anybody an idea how to solve or how to get the needed files in the requested folder?

Thanks!

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 130):

**mcrypt** extension is not provided with the PHP source since [7.2](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.other-changes.php) , but are instead available [through **PECL**](https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt). To install a **PECL** extension in [docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/), use `pecl install` to download and compile it, then use `docker-php-ext-enable` to enable it:

```bash
pecl install mcrypt-1.0.5
docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt
```

Before the `pecl install` you may need to install/update the package `libmcrypt-dev`

```bash
apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev
```

Comment: FYI, I had to remove `mcrypt` from the line where it was trying to install it, as well as add the text in this question. After that, it all seemed to work.

Comment: @Hans, do you mean `apt-get remove mcrypt` to remove it?

Comment: you need to install libmcrypt-dev  package first

Comment: @tim - no, Hans means that his line `docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt ...` needs to have `mcrypt` removed; mcrypt can't be installed via `docker-php-ext-install` (because mcrypt is no longer available as a normal extension).  `pecl install mcrypt-1.0.2` is the command to use now. To make mcrypt available for use, also do enable, as shown in this answer.

Comment: And if you want to use it with PHP 7.4, you need to use mcrypt-1.0.3.

Comment: I get `error: mcrypt.h not found. Please reinstall libmcrypt.`

Comment: You may need to update libmcrypt-dev package

Answer (score 24):

Building on MoiioM's answer, this worked for me using the `7.2-stretch` Docker image from [PHP](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/)

```bash
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
    && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.4 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt
```

Answer (score 10):

To install `mcrypt` extension you have to make sure you did install `libmcrypt-dev` which is required.

Try to add:

```
RUN apt install libmcrypt-dev
```

before you are trying to install extensions for php.

**Update**

Try to run first:

```
docker-php-ext-configure mcrypt
```

and then

```
docker-php-ext-install mcrypt
```

Comment: I use that command in my Dockerfile but it is not working. I added it to my post.

Comment: not work either. it says "Possible values for ext-name:
bcmath bz2 calendar ctype curl dba dom enchant exif fileinfo filter ftp gd gettext gmp hash iconv imap interbase intl json ldap mbstring mysqli oci8 odbc opcache pcntl pdo pdo_dblib pdo_firebird pdo_mysql pdo_oci pdo_odbc pdo_pgsql pdo_sqlite pgsql phar posix pspell readline recode reflection session shmop simplexml snmp soap sockets sodium spl standard sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm tidy tokenizer wddx xml xmlreader xmlrpc xmlwriter xsl zend_test zip"

Comment: error: /usr/src/php/ext/libmcrypt-dev does not exist