# Bitbucket Pipeline - PHP extension zip is missing

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to set up pipelines on bitbucket and I'm receiving an error when composer runs

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for craftcms/cms 3.1.24 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.1.24].
    - craftcms/cms 3.1.24 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
```

I'm not sure exactly what I need to add to my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file.

This is my current file:

```
image: php:7.2
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip git rsync zip 
            - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
            - composer install
            - php deploy.php
```

This guy seems to have a similar issue, but I'm not sure how he solved. It's vague and he also seems to have more output regarding mcrypt: [Docker: bitbucket pipelines ext-zip *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348386/docker-bitbucket-pipelines-ext-zip)

If you're curious, I got my configuration from this suggested commit at fortrabbit.com: https://gist.github.com/ukautz/4f3219c3eb5d97fbd018027dca4b8808

The php file it's running is on the link above, but it doesn't reach that yet, so it's irrelevant to my problem

I'm not entirely sure what I have to install or if I'm just not seeing the actual problem logged (for instance if there's more granular logs somewhere and I'm not seeing the actual issue)

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by installing `libzip-dev` and executing the `docker-php-ext-install zip` and `docker-php-ext-enable zip` commands.

Here is a part of my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`:

```
  step:
    caches:
      - composer
    script:
      - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip libzip-dev
      - docker-php-ext-install zip
      - docker-php-ext-enable zip
      - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
      - composer install
```

Your `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` would look like this:

```
image: php:7.2
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip git rsync zip libzip-dev
            - docker-php-ext-install zip
            - docker-php-ext-enable zip
            - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
            - composer install
            - php deploy.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get passed this by adding the following:

`zlib1g-dev` after the `-y` flag

and then these two lines

```
  - docker-php-ext-install zip
  - docker-php-ext-enable zip
```

Before `composer install`

This will run the install every time though. If anyone knows a better way, please let me know