# Error on RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mcrypt mbstring

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to create image for laravel 6 .

Here is my yml file code

```
version: '3'

services:
    lara_six_ws:
    container_name: lara_six_ws
    image: laravel-six-image
    restart: always
ports:
  - 9000:80
networks:
  - lara-six-ws-network
env_file:
  - ./lara-six-ws-prod.env
networks:
  lara-six-ws-network:
```

Here is my docker file code

```
FROM php:7.2.2-fpm
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev openssl
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mcrypt mbstring
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mcrypt mbstring
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN composer install

EXPOSE 80
```

When I run **docker build -t laravel-six-image .**
ERROR [3/8] RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mcrypt mbstring

Comment: Please do not replace question with new one using edit. Ask new question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker-php-ext-install mcrypt missing folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671108/docker-php-ext-install-mcrypt-missing-folder)