# How to install php-mcrypt in lando with php 7.2?

Tags: php, docker, php-7.2, lando

Following example in [How to install mcrypt on Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181369/how-to-install-mcrypt-on-docker/53466129#53466129) I came to this:

```
name: myapp
  recipe: drupal7
  config:
    webroot: web
    php: '7.2'
proxy:
  pma:
    - pma.myapp.lndo.site
services:
  pma:
    type: phpmyadmin
appserver:
  extras:
    - "apt-get update -y"
    - "apt-get install libmcrypt-dev"
    - "pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1"
    - "docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt"
```

After rebuilding I see:

```
$ lando php -m | grep mcrypt
mcrypt
```

But in my web application when I look at the page with phpinfo(), then there is no trace of mcrypt. Please help me out to install php-mcrypt correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue in installing php7.2-mcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48275494/issue-in-installing-php7-2-mcrypt)

Comment: https://docs.devwithlando.io/tutorials/php.html#adding-or-removing-extensions  `extras:` exchange `build_as_root:`

Comment: Please note that it does install, but only for CLI. For Apache it still does not appear in phpinfo(); even when using build_as_root. I think that docker-php-ext-enable is at fault. Apparently it only enables it for CLI PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you've missed:

```
services:
  appserver:
    build_as_root:
      - apt-get update -y
      - apt-get install libmcrypt-dev
      - pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
      - docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt
```

You can use the following:

```
name: myapp
  recipe: drupal7
  config:
    webroot: web
    php: '7.2'
proxy:
  pma:
    - pma.myapp.lndo.site
services:
  pma:
    type: phpmyadmin
  appserver:
    build_as_root:
      - apt-get update -y
      - apt-get install libmcrypt-dev
      - pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
      - docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt
```

Answer (score 0):

Made it work with:

```
services:
  appserver:
    build_as_root:
      - apt-get update -y
      - apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev
      - pecl install mcrypt
      - docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt
```